# Stable version for Graph Gym execution

Tags: python, graph, deep-learning, pytorch, geometry

My trouble is happened when running a single experiment from:
https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/graphgym.html

```
(graphenv) D:\graph\pytorch_geometric\graphgym>bash run_single.sh
run_single.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
run_single.sh: line 4: python: command not found
run_single.sh: line 5: python: command not found
run_single.sh: line 6: python: command not found
```

when I tried to run in command inside the sh file with code as below:

```
python main.py --cfg configs/pyg/example_link.yaml --repeat 3
```

the error occur like this:

```
Tried to access nonexistent attribute or method 'crow_indices' of type 'Tensor'.:
  File "C:\Users\rs085237\Miniconda3\envs\graphenv\lib\site-packages\torch_sparse\tensor.py", line 109
    def from_torch_sparse_csr_tensor(self, mat: torch.Tensor,
                                     has_value: bool = True):
        rowptr = mat.crow_indices()
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- HERE
        col = mat.col_indices()
```

1. The first error I am not sure what is happened cause I add python.exe in Path and check python --version (which already have).
2. The second error which I am trying to figure out solution in which might be the problem of torch version (the latest is quite not stable). So stable version from your experience could do help.

My computer is using:

- Window 10
- Python version: 3.8.13
- Bash version: 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
- Pytorch version: 1.8.2
- CUDA version:  11.1.1
- CUDNN version: 8.1.0.77

Comment: Judging from the first error you don’t seem to execute the bash script from a bash shell. This \r error usually comes up when executing scripts from eg Linux in Windows, because of the different line endings.

Comment: yes, I add bash from git, then add to path in environment. If I use bash shell, I have to come to other computer.

Answer (score 1):

Same error here.

It seems something is wrong with the module 'torch_sparse'.

In my case, I solved this problem by manually reinstalling torch_sparse.

Enter https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-1.8.1+cu111.html (depending on which version you installed), I downloaded 'torch_sparse-0.6.10-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl'.

Then open powershell in downloads path,
type 'pip install ./torch_sparse-0.6.10-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl'

Try my code again. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

For those who had the same problem. WSL2 is solution.

Hereby the link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install

Linux is better solution for graphgym experimental.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33101704)